# Mongo client API with resource token

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have been trying to use a Mongo API cosmos account with multiple databases and wanted to generate resource token for the individual resources. I am seeing the implementation for Document DB like below.

```
client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), resourceToken);
```

However, I am looking for implementation related to Mongo.Driver

```
MongoClientSettings settings = new MongoClientSettings();
        settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress(host, 10255);
        settings.UseSsl = true;
        settings.SslSettings = new SslSettings();
        settings.SslSettings.EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;

        MongoIdentity identity = new MongoInternalIdentity(dbName, userName);
        MongoIdentityEvidence evidence = new PasswordEvidence(tokepass2);

        settings.Credential = new MongoCredential("SCRAM-SHA-1", identity, evidence);

        MongoClient client = new MongoClient(settings);
```

I am trying to replace the "tokepass2" with the resource token that is generated. But that is not working and ended up with the exception

```
One or more errors occurred. (Unable to authenticate using sasl protocol mechanism SCRAM-SHA-1.)
```

I know we have the possibility where we can do a REST based post call with the token in the header, however I am looking for an implementation related to Mongo Client, if some one has implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately,i don't think it could be implemented in the C# Mongo DB driver.Based on [Wire protocol compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-introduction#wire-protocol-compatibility) :

> Azure Cosmos DB implements wire protocols of common NoSQL databases
>   including Cassandra, MongoDB, Gremlin, and Azure Tables Storage. By
>   providing a native implementation of the wire protocols directly and
>   efficiently inside Cosmos DB, it allows existing client SDKs, drivers,
>   and tools of the NoSQL databases to interact with Cosmos DB
>   transparently. Cosmos DB does not use any source code of the databases
>   for providing wire-compatible APIs for any of the NoSQL databases.
>
> By default, new accounts created using Azure Cosmos DB's API for
>   MongoDB are compatible with version 3.6 of the MongoDB wire protocol.
>   Any MongoDB client driver that understands this protocol version
>   should be able to natively connect to Cosmos DB.

Cosmos db mongo api only implements wire protocols for Mongo DB,it doesn't have any specific sdk for mongo db. And other mongo db driver like mongo c# driver or mongoose etc,they built for mongo db,not for cosmos db mongo api. So the resource token feature can't be supported by those drivers directly. You can't replace master key with resource token.

If you do want to use resource token,you could use :

1.REST API as you mentioned in your question

2.Migrate mongo db to cosmos db sql api. Please refer to this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data

Comment: @Darey You're welcome,Darey. If you think my answer is beneficial for you,would you please accept it as an answer,thanks  a lot.